# Radio Button Visual Basic MVC 4

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pretty new with MVC and especially with Visual Basic. After looking up all kinds of online examples for radio buttons in C# I still can't see it translating into VB.

Can anyone help out with a simple explanation on how to pas a value through a radio button. That is just simply pass an integer 0, 1 or 2 etc.. then I will do an if else in my controller to handle it.

I've been trying something like that

```
@Html.RadioButton("ButtonName", "1", True)
```

And then I want to pick that up back in the controller as in

```
Dim selection As Integer = ...
If selection == 1 Then
etc...
```

sorry for the bad explanation syntax. In plain words

```
<input type="radio" name="SomeName" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="SomeName" value="2">
```

Then get back the value that was checked.

Thank you so much

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you're reading the value back.

Comment: In my Model I have declared an integer called selection. And I want to pass it an integer from the radio button View. Not sure how the code will look in the controller. I've seen this too 
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(b) b.SelectedAnswer, b.ID) 
but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your model

```
public class YourModel{
     int RadioValue{get;set;}
     ....
}
```

Your view

```
@using namspace;
@model YourModel
@using(Html.BeginForm(....)){
  @Html.RadioButton("RadioValue", 1, True)  @* The first parameter is name, and must match the name of the property you are binding to. *@
  @Html.RadioButton("RadioValue", 2, False) 
}
```

Your Controller

```
public ActionResult(YourModel model)
{
  //Get value
  model.RadioValue....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I needed, I will give it a try in the morning!

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor` is a far better option typically.